# Check if a file exists and use return() to return a string variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have two files:
I need to inclide **a.php** in **b.php** then call the a function to return a string variable and print it.

**a.php:**

```php
function CheckExist($file) {
  $response;
  
  if (file_exists($file) {
    $response = "File Extisted";
  } else { 
    $response = "File Not Existed";
  }
  
  return $response;
}
```

**b.php**

```php
// Some code to include a.php and call the function to get the string variable
print($response);
```

Comment: Uhm.... Did you even try to fund a solution? Maybe start with the php documentation, for example the documentation on how to call functions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php Surely you will also be able to find how to `require` files....

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to include file a.php in b.php and be able to use the function in a.php.

In PHP, you can include files using [require_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php), [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) and [include_once](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) statements which you should have probably known about before asking this question.

To suggest a solution while you read from the links I have provided, you can use any of the above functions to include your file a.php, call the function and save the return value in a variable and print it out:

**b.php**

```
require("a.php");
$response = CheckExists("a-sample-file.txt");
print($response);
```

Comment: Add `;` to the lines at the end. And `require`s are not functions but statements, otherwise good answer.

Comment: Thank you...It was an oversight